# Creating Firebreath starter project on Windows

Tags: firebreath

I realize that this is more of a bug report for firebreath and I have reported it as such, but I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this issue.

I have been following the steps to install firebreath and getting it up and running for Windows and VS2013, from:

http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Building+on+Windows

and from the step-by-step video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmYbz6R6q3s

After pulling from the git repo, updating the submodule, and running the python, there is a problem with running the Visual Studio prep script. Though the script runs and completes, it displays these messages...

```
 CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:118 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0045 is not set: Error on non-existent target in
  get_target_property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0045" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  get_target_property() called with non-existent target "boost_thread".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:92 (add_boost_library)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:118 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0045 is not set: Error on non-existent target in
  get_target_property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0045" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  get_target_property() called with non-existent target "boost_system".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/3rdParty/boost/libs/thread/CMakeLists.txt:64 (add_boost_library)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:104 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0045 is not set: Error on non-existent target in
  get_target_property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0045" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  get_target_property() called with non-existent target "ScriptingCore".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

project dir: C:/Users/LucidocAdmin/Code/TestPlugin
Single project: C:/Users/LucidocAdmin/Code/TestPlugin
Generating plugin configuration files in C:/Users/LucidocAdmin/Code/build/projects/TestPlugin/gen
CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:118 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0045 is not set: Error on non-existent target in
  get_target_property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0045" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  get_target_property() called with non-existent target "boost_date_time".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/common.cmake:97 (add_boost_library)
  tests/ScriptingCoreTest/CMakeLists.txt:57 (link_boost_library)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/common.cmake:118 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0045 is not set: Error on non-existent target in
  get_target_property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0045" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  get_target_property() called with non-existent target "boost_regex".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/common.cmake:97 (add_boost_library)
  tests/ScriptingCoreTest/CMakeLists.txt:58 (link_boost_library)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/LucidocAdmin/Code/build
```

In an attempt to fool myself that these messages would not be a problem, I continued on with the rest of the steps, all of which compiled and installed, only to be left with a generated plugin page and a message:

> Plugin not working :(

There were no other errors/warnings that presented themselves throughout the process except for these messages. I have tried running different versions of firebreath with different versions of VS and all of them have these messages and all of the plugins end up broken.

What's going on, and how can I fix it?

Edit: For anyone else having an similar issue, the browsers were recognizing the plugin but were not allowing it to run. After a quick change in settings allowed the plugin to load and run. I am still curious in these errors though and still would like any other information that could be offered on the subject.

Comment: Does dll for plugin generated? Try register it manually `gersvr32 myplugin.dll`. See plugin list in browser: is your plugin in list?

Comment: I ended up finding out that the browsers were recognizing the plugin but were not allowing it to run. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I think you should create an answer  for your question. May be it will useful for somebody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors displayed are due to the FireBreath 1.x project not yet being updated to work properly with cmake 3.  If you use cmake 2.8.11.2 it should work fine.